# How to use Composite command in mvvm

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, prism

**Intro**
I'm working with WPF with [MVVM-Light](https://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/) application

**Goal**

I have to invoke two commands from the same event, Is this possible using MVVM.?

*Xaml look like this*

```
 <i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
        <command:EventToCommand Command="{Binding Command1}" PassEventArgsToCommand="False" />
        <command:EventToCommand Command="{Binding Command2}" PassEventArgsToCommand="False" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

**Problem**

> When hooking two commands only one of them is invoked while triggering the event.

**Q1 How to invoke two commands in a event?**

> I have heard about [Composite commands in PRISM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg405494(v=pandp.40).aspx)

For example, the `CompositeCommand` class is used in the [Stock Trader Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg405494(v=pandp.40).aspx) Implementation (Stock Trader RI) in order to implement the `SubmitAllOrders` command represented by the Submit All button in the buy/sell view. **When the user clicks the Submit All button, each `SubmitCommand` defined by the individual buy/sell transactions is executed.**

.
**Q2 Is there anything like this in MVVM ?**

Comment: For question 2: probably everything you can  do  is to define CompositeCommand separately and pass array of Commands as a CommandParameter to it. And then in the RelayCommand get the arguments and invoke each  of the passed command separately.

Comment: Yes, that ring a bell

Answer (score 2):

Try using 2 event triggers:

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
        <command:EventToCommand Command="{Binding Command1}" PassEventArgsToCommand="False" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
        <command:EventToCommand Command="{Binding Command2}" PassEventArgsToCommand="False" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```